# Sending and receiving an OpenCV Mat object in a multicast network

Tags: c++, opencv, serialization, deserialization, multicast

I have a use case to send an OpenCV `Mat` object to multiple receivers in a multicast network. I use C++ `boost` library to send and receive the multicast network data.

> My understanding

`Mat` object is serialized to a `boost` buffer and sent to network receivers. Receivers receive and deserialize the buffer to construct a `Mat` object.

> Implementation I tried

My `Mat` object to be sent is `image`.

```cpp
const char * px = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(image.data);
socket_.async_send_to(
            boost::asio::buffer(px, sizeof(px)), endpoint_,
            [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                if (!ec && message_count_ < max_message_count)
                    do_timeout();
            });
```

> Question 1

How to check if the complete data has reached the receiver?

> Question 2

How to reconstruct the `Mat` object at receiver?

> Question 3

Is there a better way to construct an image buffer which transfer OpenCV `Mat` objects in a multicast network? (I appreciate the use of `boost` library since it is used at multiple places)

Comment: Which type of image data are you sending?

Comment: I'm grabbing my webcam feed to a `Mat` object using OpenCV.

Comment: For the reconstruction you will need more information than only data. You will need to know width and height of the image also the original type from OpenCv e.g CV_8UC1 or other to properly reinterpret the data in there. I am not sure but you might also need stride value

Comment: Use google protobuf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810026/sending-protobuf-messages-with-boostasio